# Is there an event fired when a VPN is connected in .Net 4.7.1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a program that starts processes to connect to an OpenVPN VPN.

This works and using a timer to check a ping to verify the connection has completed works, but it would be better to use an event instead of a timer.

I've tried `NetworkAvailabilityChanged`, but this doesn't fire when an existing network is already available when the VPN is connected.

Is there an event I can use for this?

Comment: You'd have to register for NLM events: [Network List Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_nla/), e.g., [INetworkEvents::NetworkAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetworkevents-networkadded) -- See whether you get a `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message when you wire up the VPN.